# CSS Adding margin bottom to <tr> that has a background color with borders

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

Want i am after is that i got this table where every row has a background color with rounded borders. The problem i got is that i need to add a margin bottom to the  since the table has collapse on it. so the table looks like this

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>stuff</td>
   <td>stuff2</td>
   <td>stuff3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then there is alot of these rows and for every row i want a specific background with rounded borders and so far i have managed. using

```css
.colored-row td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 1px;
}

.colored-row td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 1px;
}

.colored-row td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}

.colored-row td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
}

.colored-row {
    background: #374F60;
}
```

the problem comes after this because i also want to have a margin between each row and i tried by adding the margin a `<div>` inside the `<td>` since on `<tr>` it made no difference but on `<td>` the color just keep expanding with the margin and if i put the color on the `<td>` aswell it gets some spaces between the `<td>` where the color aint applied.

so i want it to have a margin like this for the whole row. is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add `margins` to a `tr` element. THe only way that would work is if you would use`display:block` on the `tr`. But that would cause the `tr` to have the width according to it's content not to the width of the table.

One solution would be ( if you can edit the HTML ) to add a `separator` row between your colored rows and give it a height.

```css
.colored-row td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.colored-row td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.colored-row {
  background: #374F60;
}

.separator {
  height: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="colored-row">
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff2</td>
    <td>stuff3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="separator"></tr>
  <tr class="colored-row">
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff2</td>
    <td>stuff3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: or, you could use `border-spacing` but it only works when `border-collapse` it's set to `separate`. But this will add a 'space at the top' also to the first row

```css
.colored-row td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.colored-row td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.colored-row {
  background: #374F60;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 15px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="colored-row">
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff2</td>
    <td>stuff3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="colored-row">
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff2</td>
    <td>stuff3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm it works for the margin part but the tds still gets clamped into a small area instead of suing the tables full width

Comment: @JohanJönsson the table didn't have a width set. it had the width of it's content. Now i added a width to the table so you can see the td's stretch and cover the whole width of the table.

Comment: I still get the same problem but as i see it working on your i mark it as the right one and i have to try to see why mine doesnt work the same :)